# Isolate an emacs frame

Tags: emacs

I normally open a new emacs frame when context switching to a different project.
Unfortunately, `find-file` history is shared between frames.
Is it possible to open a new frame which is 'blank', i.e. doesn't remember any of the state from any other frame?

Comment: Stating the obvious, but you could just start a new instance of Emacs. I presume you would prefer not to deal with the associated start-up time, though?

Comment: Didn't actually think of this! But just noticed that it doesn't work for emacsclientw.exe (Windows version of emacs) - that just switches to any existing window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

find-file does not make distinctions between frames, you could launch a new emacs if you want to separate your environments :

<kbd>M-&</kbd> `emacs` <kbd>RET</kbd>

NB : `emacs` should be in your path.